# order of $x \operatorname{mod} p(x)$ in $\mathbb Z_2$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, finite-fields

I am writing a software that analyze the behavior of an LFSR given its feedback polynomial. At some point, I need to compute the order of  $x \operatorname{mod} p(x)$ in $\mathbb Z_2$. In mathematical terms I am looking for the smallest positive integer $k$ such that 
$x^k\equiv 1\pmod {p(x)}$. $p(x)$ being a given polynomial with coeficient in $\mathbb Z_2$ ($0$ or $1$).

Some naive questions about that:

- what is $k$ for $p(x)=0, 1$ or $x$ ? any convention on those cases ?
- Is there a well known, efficient algorithm for that ?
- Is there a software that I can use to generate test vectors (testing against an exhaustive search does not scale very well...)

Comment: The order of $x$ is defined only, when $x$ is a unit of the ring $\Bbb{Z}_2[x]/\langle p(x)\rangle$. For this to be the case it is necessary and sufficient that $x$ and $p(x)$ don't have any common divisors. This in turn is equivalent to $p(0)=1$. If $p(x)$ is irreducible of degree $n$, then the order is always a factor of $2^n-1$, i.e. a factor of what you would get with a primitive $p(x)$. Furthermore, in that case the order will not be a factor of $2^\ell-1$ for any $\ell\mid n$, which allows you to eliminate some cases.

Comment: Thanks for the hints, could you explain the meaning of L|n, does it mean any L smaller than n, or perhaps any L coprime to n ?

Comment: It means that $\ell$ divides $n$, i.e. is a factor of $n$. I forgot to specify that $\ell$ is a proper factors, in other words we also have $\ell<n$. For example if $m$ is the order of $x$ modulo $p(x)$, where $p$ is irreducible of degree $8$, then $m$ will be a factor of $2^8-1=255$, but will not be a factor of $2^4-1=15$. Thus we can deduce that $m$ is one of $17, 51, 85, 255$.

Comment: Factoring integers of the form $2^n-1$ is probably a lot easier than factoring general integers. But, in a program, I would consider using a look up table of such factorizations for $n$ up to some bound, and declare factors larger than that out of bounds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Special cases:
   As stated by Jyrki, the order of x is not defined for polynomials p(x) of degree 0 or degree >= 1 if p(0)=0.
2. Algorithm:
   After spending a fair amount of time searching, I think the best algorithm to compute the order of x is given in "Finite Fields" by Lidl & Niederreiter.
   It says the following:
   let f be a reducible polynomial: f = f1^b1 * ... * fk^bk
   Then ord(f)=e * 2^t
   With e=lcm(ord(f1),...,ord(fk)) and t smallest integer such that 2^t>=max(b1,...bk)
   To compute the order of x for irreducible polynomials, it gives the following algorithm:
   let m be the degree of an irreducible polynomial p(x)
   if p(x) is primitive, ord(p) = (2^m)-1.
   Otherwise, let n = (2^m)-1 = (p1 ^r1) * ... * (pk^rk)

   ```
   set ordx = 1
   For each factor pi:
       set t = ri
       set divider = pi
       while(t>1)
           set exp = n/divider (should always be an integer division since divider is always a factor of n.)
           if x^exp mod p(x) != 1
               ordx = ordx * pi^t
               t=0 (break the loop to look at next pi)
           else
               t = t - 1
               divider = divider * pi
       end while
   end foreach
   ```

   result is ordx

   As indicated by Jyrki, one can discard some of the factors before going through the main loop, see his first comment on the original question.
3. Software
   I did not find any software which compute the order of x out of the box (well I looked only at what can be evaluated free of charge). My implementation of the algorithm presented above is available here: http://www.nimp.co.uk/software/z2PolyAnalysis.zip (I tested it as hard as I could, still I would not call that a reference, if you get some different result with another tool, please let me know!)